# Pass element tag Id for typeahead

Tags: javascript, html, typeahead.js

I have a table where there are inputs with typeahead on each row. The row has an id and I'd like to pass this to the typeahead function.

```
<table>
...
<tr data-id="1"><td><input type="text" class="form-control addTag" /></td></tr>
<tr data-id="2"><td><input type="text" class="form-control addTag" /></td></tr>
...
</table>
```

and then my javascript:

```
$('.addTag').typeahead({
       source: function (query, process) {

       var timeReportId = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
```

$(this) does not seem to be the input element though. I can't figure out which row it is called from.

Comment: Are you generating each row from a javascript function or is this plain html?

Comment: It's plain HTML (rendered from asp.net-mvc)

Comment: @ekenman if you have solved this one I'm curious. Trying to use the typeahed.js library too and it's failing to even work with ANY of the demo code (HTML/JS) they provide in the examples set. So far I'm able to get my array built using my own JS, but nothing fires on an class="typeahead" HTML entry item I've created and attempted to align to the JS underpinnings.

Comment: No, haven't figured this one out. I'm thinking about using autocomplete instead. @iamstrained